# how to get googleTokenID and googleAccessToken in Firebase Authentication on Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-signin

On the official documentation of Firebase Authentication, the guide is only available on how you can get the `googleAccessToken` on native Android & iOS. No solution is available for Unity on their official guide.

[image: Official Documentation showing the issue]

The closest solution I have found is to use the Google Play Services plugin for Unity to get the access token, which is not a good solution for the cross-platform as the following plugin is deprecated on the iOS platform. So yah, your code will not work on iOS.

Also, I believe it's an expensive solution to add a plugin for a "googleIdToken".

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Comment: @Pramod, a little late but here you go https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity

Answer (score 2):

This process is complicated and Firebase documentation is not helping.

To address this issue Google recently released Google Sign-In plugin for Unity.

You can find detailed instructions on the read me file.

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity

Answer (score -3):

The fire base documentation seems to have a unity SDK to achieve what you're wanting to do.

You then include the GoogleService-Info.plist for ios.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add_the_sdk_to_your_app

the GoogleService-Info.plist for ios is in your google console.

Comment: Hey, this is the same link we are visiting each one is suggesting, please provide some useful, which really can help.

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted, probably be the poster above commenting on a 2 year old question. This links I provided are still valid and the goolge doc page link in my answer has youtube vid walkthroughs as well.

Comment: its because the plist does not contain a GoogleIDtoken - maybe if you actually read - this is not an issue of connecting the app to the project which is what the plist does for iOS.